# windows cmd syntax remove first word i text file on every line

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

Hi I want following behavior in batch script windows 2012 or later.
scenario:

Example input.txt:

```
Word1 Word2 Word3.......Wordn 
Word1 Word2 Word3.......Wordn 
Word1 Word2 Word3.......Wordn 
Word1 Word2 Word3.......Wordn
```

Example output.txt:

```
Word2 Word3 ........Wordn
Word2 Word3 ........Wordn
Word2 Word3 ........Wordn
Word2 Word3 ........Wordn
```

Used syntax:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=1,* usebackq" %%a in ("input.txt") do @echo %%b)>"output.txt"
```

type output.txt  give just rubish

```
%b
%b
%b
%b
```

tested without @ but no difference, Checked in many examples apparently it should have been working in older windows.

Comment: That should work in a batch file. Judging by the output, you are running the code from the command line (no batch file). See `for /?` for the difference between `%a` and `%%a`.

Comment: tested with % and %%  result is the same also no difference in output running batch or testing from command line....  instead of removing first word in every line from "input.txt" it is just echoing "%b" in every line....removing all context.